# How can I show rows data in my modal when I click the row

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

My codes are

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(() => {
 
$.ajax({

 
    url: "http://localhost:3000/etiket2", 
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response){
     
        if(response.length > 0){
            for(let index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {
                var newRow = $('<tr data-toggle="modal"  data-id='+ ++index + 'data-target="#myModalAdd'+ '>');
                var cols = "";
                var okuyucu = '';
                var x = '';
                var y = '';
                var id='';
                --index
                cols += '<td>' + response[index].id+'</td>';
                cols += '<td> '+ response[index].isim +'</td>' ;
                cols += '<td> '+ response[index].mac +'</td>';
           
                newRow.append(cols);
                $("#example2 .tbody").append(newRow);
            }  

        }
    }
})
})


$('#example2').on('click',function(){
    $("#myModalAdd").modal("show");
    var name = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").html();
  var email = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").html();

$('#okuyucu').val(name);
  $('#x').val(email);
 
});
</script>
```

when I click the second or any other rows it always shows my first row in my modal.How can I fix my problem.where is my problem in my code

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Inside loop create separate modal for every row and also put the data you want to show in it, so for every iteration you have a modal with associated data in it. Just open the right one.
2. Create a single modal and for every row make an ajax call and pass the unique id and get the data, put it in modal fields and the open it.